# If Else in html web page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up an html web page that depends on the user entering a certain word in one text box to make another text box display a different word. Ultimately the use of this feature will become more complex but for now I just want to make that simple routine work. I've written code but it doesn't seem to follow the logic. When I click on the button no matter what is in text1 both text1 and text2 show "Dog" and "Cat" respectively. Here's my code that isn't working:

```
enter code here
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
      if (Text1.value = "Dog") 
      {
          Text2.value = "Cat";
      }
      else
      {
          Text2.value = "Mouse";
      }
  }
</script>
<br><br><br><br>
<font size=6 face=arial color=#336699>
<b>TestRoutine</b>
<br><br>
</font>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="myFunction()"> 
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="Text2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `Text1.value` and `Text2.value` with:

```
document.getElementById("Text1").value
```

and

```
document.getElementById("Text2").value
```

respectively.

Also, when making comparisons in your `if` statement, you should you `===` instead of `=` to actually compare the values.

**Edit:** You should actually use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: `DOMNode.value` is always a string so you don't need the type coercion from `==`. Use `===`.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't have a full understanding of when to use `===` vs `==`. The latter `==` would still work in this scenario, but I guess the former is better.

Answer (score 2):

1. You never define `Text1`. You want `var Text1 = document.getElementById('Text1');`
2. `=` is an **assignment**. You need to use `===` for a comparison (or `==` for a comparison with type coercion)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it thanks to the suggestions and tried not to fix the parts that i do not like.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById("Text1").value === "Dog") 
      {
          document.getElementById("Text2").value = "Cat";
      }
      else
      {
          document.getElementById("Text2").value = "Mouse";;
      }
  }
</script>
<br><br><br><br>
<font size=6 face=arial color=#336699>
<b>TestRoutine</b>
<br><br>
</font>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="myFunction()"> 
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<input id="Text2" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great. Now I want to make the if statement link to another page instead of filling Text2. The other page would be something like FileDownload.htm.

Comment: I found it!parent.document.location.href = "Docx.htm";

Comment: What I meant to say is that I found it.